# Запуск сервера Gunicorn в Django

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

В доках : `$ gunicorn myproject.wsgi`
Не могу понять где в моем приложении объект *.wsgi и должен ли быть по дефолту?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, он есть по дефолту.Он лежит в папке с названием проекта, где находится `settings.py`. Собственно в примере его и вызывают из этой папки, нужно заменить `myproject` на имя вашего проекта.

```
.
└── test_for_stack
    ├── manage.py
    └── test_for_stack
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── settings.py
        ├── urls.py
        └── wsgi.py     <-- Вот он
```

Comment: Странно, но я его у себя не нахожу, запустился $ gunicorn название проекта.wsgi

Comment: предположу, что пытаетесь найти его в папке, где лежит `manage.py`, а  нужно вызывать из папки глубже, где лежит `settings.py`. Тогда просто добавится еще одна директория типа `myproject.myproject.wsgi`. Добавил структуру только что созданного проекта в ответ

Comment: @Baterson: нужно как раз вызывать из папки где лежит `manage.py`, используя имя `myproject.wsgi`.

Comment: @jfs я не так выразился, я имел ввиду, что он находится на директорию ниже. в папке с названием названием проекта.

Answer (score 2):

`myproject.wsgi` это название модуля, который содержит `application` объект (входная точка для WSGI приложения).

Ищется он также как и любой другой модуль в Питоне (представьте что происходит во время `import myproject.wsgi`).

В случае django, если вы запустите эту команду из той же директории, где ваш `manage.py` находится, то `PYTHONPATH` будет содержать `myproject` пакет из текущей рабочей директории автоматически (как это обычно бывает когда вы любой Питон скрипт запускаете). Вместо `myproject` вы должны своё имя проекта указать (имя которое вы использовали в `startproject` команде):

```
$ django-admin startproject your_project
$ tree your_project
your_project
├── manage.py
└── your_project
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py

$ cd your_project
your_project$ gunicorn your_project.wsgi
```